# Bind MasterDetailPage from ViewModel in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind my masterdetailpage detail from viewmodel. But it doesn't work.

Here's my code in view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailsSamp1"
         x:Class="MasterDetailsSamp1.MainPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MasterDetailsSamp1.ViewModels">
<MasterDetailPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MasterDetailsViewModel/>
</MasterDetailPage.BindingContext>

<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
        <StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>

    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Here's my code in my viewmodel

```
public MasterDetailsViewModel()
{
    MasterDetailPage masterDetailPage = new MasterDetailPage
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)))
    };
}
```

It's working when I put this line of code

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)))
```

behind the code, but I want to achieve it from view model.

Please help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to add binding context on your Master and detail like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    x:Class="MasterDetailExample.Main"
    Title="Master Detail Example">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
      <ContentPage Padding="5, 25"  BindingContext="{Binding Menu}" Title="Master">
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
              <Label Text="Master" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
              <Label Text="{Binding Subtitle}" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
          </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage>

    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <ContentPage>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

To change your detail page in ViewModel I use this :

```
(Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(YOURDETAILPAGE)));
```

I'm not sure if it's the best way to this job, MVVM and MasterDetail documentions need to be clarify.

Don't forget that your binding context item need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to work.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yeah, I know. What I mean is that, the should be called from ViewModel now creating a contentpage layout inside the MasterDetailPage.Detail :)

Comment: To add up, I also have my INotifyPropertyChanged in my ViewModel and everything's working. The problem is, when I put this code "Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HomePage)))" in my viewmodel, it doesn't work. But if you put that behind the code after the InitializeComponent() of the page, it's working.

Comment: I'm having an error. It says "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>"